# Android APK certificate matches prior APK but does not upgrade

Tags: android

I have signed my APK with the same private key as earlier releases.  I've also compared the certificates with the following command.

unzip -p  META-INF/CERT.RSA |openssl pkcs7 -inform DER -out 1.txt  -print_certs

I run the command above on the 2 APKs and then diff the output.  When I do that, there are no differences in the file.

Yet, when I attempt to upgrade the app, I am asked to uninstall and install the new app instead of an in-place upgrade.

Any thoughts on why an APK signature can match yet, they can prompt us to take the right actions.

Comment: So, you sign your app then copy the api to your device and install. is that the case? are you sure that the old app installed on device not installed by eclipse or android studio?

Comment: Did you try the following: 1. uninstall current version 2. sign apk, copy and install 3. then, again sign apk, copy and install?

Comment: ignore my previous comments. you are installing app by moving it to device? or from play store?

Comment: Thans for the help.  I'm installing the app by moving it to the device, not from the Play Store.